# PowerShell: "The given path's format is not supported" when path does not contain folders. Using Split-Path

Tags: powershell

I have a function that returns a folder name with full path, like C:\Folder\Subfolder.

I then extract the name of the subfolder using Split-Path.

It works like expected when its folders or subfolders like C:\Folder or C:\Folder\Subfolder, but not when a drive is selected

Here's my code. The "Get-folder" function is just a file dialogue where the user can select a folder:

```
$FolderNavn = Get-Folder

$FolderNavnKort = Split-Path -Path $Foldernavn -Leaf
```

Here's what I'm expecting:

if the folder is 'C:\Folder\Subfolder' it should return "Subfolder" (works)

If the folder is just 'C:\Folder' it should return "Folder" (works)

If C:\ is selected (and thus not a folder) is should return "", but instead I get:

> Out-File : The given path's format is not supported.

When I'm testing, $FolderNavn returns "C:\".

Any suggestions?

Edit, content of Get-Folder:

```
function Get-Folder {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)]
    [string]$Message = "Please select a directory.",

    [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]$InitialDirectory = [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::MyComputer,

    [switch]$ShowNewFolderButton
)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$dialog.Description = 'Select a directory.'
$dialog.RootFolder  = $InitialDirectory
$dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = if ($ShowNewFolderButton) { $true } else { $false }
$selected = $null

# force the dialog TopMost
# Since the owning window will not be used after the dialog has been 
# closed we can just create a new form on the fly within the method call
$result = $dialog.ShowDialog((New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{TopMost = $true }))
if ($result -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
    $selected = $dialog.SelectedPath
}
# clear the FolderBrowserDialog from memory
$dialog.Dispose()
# return the selected folder
$selected
```

}

Comment: Can you share the content of your "Get-Folder" script? Running `$foldername = Split-Path -Path C:\ -Leaf` on my PC sets `$foldername` to "C:\"

Comment: Also, where does the "Out-File" part come into play?

Comment: @GuyS I've added the script. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Out-File comes into play here:

'$KanalNavne | Out-File -FilePath $KanalerStiNavn -Encoding utf8 -Append'

Comment: `$KanalerStiNavn` needs to be a filename - what's the value when you are calling `Out-File`? Can you post that part as well?

Answer (score 1):

Based on some research, it seems this is likely due to an extra colon in the file path. Without the code relevant to building the path / file (`$KanalerStiNavn`), my guess is that it's attempting to create a folder with the leaf subfolder you're retrieving earlier in this line.

```
$FolderNavnKort = Split-Path -Path $Foldernavn -Leaf
```

When you have a subfolder (such as "Subfolder", "Folder" as in your example) the returned value can be created as a folder in your desired directory in the `Out-File` command. Unfortunately, when (in the above line) your `$foldernavn` is the root, it returns "C:\" as the folder, and you try to create a folder in another directory including that

```
# Assuming the root export folder is D:\newfolder
# When $foldernavn is C:\folder (and therefore $FolderNavnKort is "folder")
$KanalerStiNavn could be "D:\newfolder\folder"

# When $foldernavn is C:\ (and therefore $FolderNavnKort is "C:\")
$KanalerStiNavn could be "D:\newfolder\C:\"
```

The second example is an invalid filename, hence the error.

To correct this you need to handle the case that the returned value of the `Split-Path` function contains a colon. Could be as simple as:

```
if ($FolderNavnKort -like "*:*")
{
    $FolderNavnKort = ""
}
```

Not overly beautiful, but should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that would also cause folders like C:\FOO to be returned as "" instead of "FOO" but I guess I could use regular expression (sigh!) or make the IF on $FolderNavn instead, and then  make a IF-THEN-ELSE. Thanks.